# How to make transparent colours using the bg=c(col.list) function in R

Tags: r, transparent, symbols, alpha

I would like to use the alpha function for making symbols transparent in a plot. However I'm using the col.list function and can't really use the solutions that are available online. This is how my script looks like (I open my data directly from excel):

```
pch.list <- rep(0, length(data$CA))
pch.list[data$CA=="TC"] <- 21
pch.list[data$CA=="TI"] <- 22
pch.list[data$CA=="AN"] <- 23
pch.list[data$CA=="AT"] <- 24

col.list <- rep(0, length(data$CA))
col.list[data$CA=="TC"] <- "blue"
col.list[data$CA=="TI"] <- "purple"
col.list[data$CA=="AN"] <- "mediumturquoise"
col.list[data$CA=="AT"] <- "white"

par(mar=c(5,5,5,5))
plot(data$Cen, data$Oen, pch=c(pch.list), main="TE", bg=c(col.list, alpha=0.3), cex= 1.5,ylim=c(-15,0), xlim=c(-20, 1))
minor.tick(nx=5, ny=5, tick.ratio=0.5)
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: We cannot reproduce your example. Please provide the variable `data` by typing   `dput(data)` and pasting the results into your question.

Comment: Where you have "blue"  replace it with `do.call(rgb, as.list(c(col2rgb("blue")[,1]/255, alpha)))`   and so on for the other colors.  where alpha is the transparency level you want (between 0 and 1).